# php mvc pass userdata

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am using a personal MVC system to create a blog. It works. 
Now I want to submit a user comment.
The thing is, I don't want to submit the user id and post id in AJAX. That would enable frawd comments.
How do I "remember" the user's session and pass it to the server?

My post look like this: `var text = encodeURI($('#folderComment').val());`

```
var text = encodeURI($('#folderComment').val());
$.post(
        "<?= URL_MVC ?>/FolderComment/add/"+text, {},
        function(data){
            var content = data.split("##");
            var html = '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + content[0] + '<br>' + content[2] + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + content[1] + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
            $('#commentsTable').prepend(html);
        });
```

Do I have to send the user's id? Because in the receiving controller I am using

```
$userid = isset($_SESSION['user']['fkuser']) ? $_SESSION['user']['fkuser'] : $defaultid;
```

this parameter works fine on the view, and the model, but, when I send AJAX request to the controller, it's not working...

Comment: Just use `$_SESSION` on your receiving php page.

Comment: hi @Erik, I have edited the question. It's not working..

Comment: so when you're using ajax `$userid` get's assigned to `$defaultid` ?

Comment: Did you start the session in the receiving controller? What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` give you?

Comment: hi @DirkMcQuickly, thanks for the reply. should I start the session in the recieving controller, if so , when and how exactly? more over, I tried `var_dump` and got null in `$_SESSION`

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION)` works in my localhost but not in my server. is there any reason for that?

Comment: well, I am not an expert on that, but I bumped into a lot of questions here on SO when googling for 'session not working on server'. At least there is a beginning of an answer to your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save the authenticated user's information in $_SESSION and it will be accessible in any request (including AJAX, considering your session cookie is available).
but about the post id, the story is a bit different, you can save the post id in session when the page is being viewed but if the user opens multiple posts at the same time the comments get mixed up, since the post id value is changed on every "view post" request.

My suggestion is to insert the post id in the form as a hidden field (you can encrypt it if you want but I see no reason for it), use it in conjunction with the user id from the session and a CSRF token to make sure the request is not forged.